# SQL Server loop programming

Tags: sql-server

For Sql Server 2014, what syntax do I need, if this is even possible?
*(in pseudo-code)*

```
DECLARE @searchstring nvarchar(20)
LOOP @searchstringstring = (SELECT keyword FROM table1)
SELECT column FROM table2 where column LIKE '%@searchstring%'
END LOOP
```

I want it to return all columns in a single table.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Maybe it can be done using a set-based solution.

Comment: you can loop through while clause or cursor in sql server. but it is not a recommended approach

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to achieve,some example will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you want to select all the values in `table2.Column` that contains the text in `table2.Keyword`. This can be done easily with a simple `inner join`:

```
SELECT t2.column
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON(t2.column LIKE '%'+ t1.keyword +'%'
```

Sql works best with set based operations. looping is rarely the desired approach.